# Assembly: copy contents of string into another register

Tags: assembly, x86, yasm

I'm having trouble figuring out how to copy the contents of one string into another. Here's what I'm working with: Given an address of a string in a register `rbx`, I need to copy the contents of that address of a string into another register(argument 4) `rdx`.

Here's what I'm currently doing

```
mov rbx, qword[rsi+16] ; rbx = some string address
; performs checks on string
; etc..
; string passes tests so
mov rbx, qword[rbx]
mov qword[rdx], rbx
```

the problem is that `qword` will only allow me to store **8** characters into rdx, while the actual maximum is 80(just an arbitrary maximum I defined in the start of my program). I could of course change `qword` to `dqword` but this doesn't sovle my problem as it would go from 8 character to 16. If I pass the string `Arguments` into the function above I would be returned `Argument`, since the copy assignment only handles 8 characters.

I apologize in advance as this is probably a really simple solution, but I'm very new to assembly. How can I move the contents of one string to another?

Comment: Only the address of the string is in the register. If you want to duplicate a string you need to allocate space somehow (depends on your environment) and copy the characters there, then load that address into a register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you write a loop to transfer 80 bytes?

```
 mov rcx,10
again:
 mov rax, qword[rbx+rcx*8-8]
 mov qword[rdx+rcx*8-8], rax
 loop again
```